# xcode 4.6 applescript open text file for reading

Tags: xcode, text, applescript

I am trying to incorporate my applescript into xcode. the script works normally with applescript but not ran in xcode.  I am trying to open the file for reading. here is the code

```
set Location to "US"
set DriverFile to "/Volumes/MacPrintDrivers/" & Location & "DriverInstall.txt"
set DriverInstallFile to POSIX file DriverFile
open for access DriverInstallFile
```

i have confirmed the file exists and i can display the contents. i can't seem to read this way in Xcode.  the error i get is

```
«script» doesn’t understand the «event rdwropen» message. (error -1708)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [set volume not working in xcode with applescript cocoa objc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555380/set-volume-not-working-in-xcode-with-applescript-cocoa-objc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASOC (AppleScript Objective-C) has some problems with scripting addition commands (such as `open for access`). Sometimes you can work around this by saying `tell current application to`, e.g. `tell current application to open for access`. But for further details I suggest you get Shane Stanley's book: http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/apps/ He has explored this in great depth.